# C# array specific letters to a txt file

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this file called **text.txt**. It contains text in Lithuanian language. I did **Encoding 1257** for it so it can read Lithuanian letters.
Now all I have to do is to make an array for each Lithuanian letter used in that file. This should show how many times each letter is repeated in a text and write those results to a new txt file.
So far I came up with this idea:

```
public static int[ ] Letters(string a) {
    string p = "AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ"; // Lithuanian letters
    int [ ]rez = new int[p.Length];
    int ind = 0;
    foreach (char r in a ) {
       ind = p.IndexOf(r);
       if (ind>=0)
           rez[ind] ++; 
    }
    return rez;
}
```

I thought this will work for a start, however I doesn't and I can't find why.

Comment: It works for me. Do you need to return which letter has what count as this just returns an array of integers in the order of whatever letter is found first?

Comment: The code you posted is fine. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem you want help with, along with a precise, clear explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. Keep in mind that "it doesn't work" is not a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> Letters(string a)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> letters = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    string p = "AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ"; // Lithuanian letters
    int ind = -1;
    foreach (char r in a)
    {
        ind = p.IndexOf(r);
        if (ind >= 0)
        {
            if (letters.ContainsKey(r.ToString()))
            {
                letters[r.ToString()] = letters[r.ToString()] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                letters.Add(r.ToString(), 1);
            }

        }
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Comment: Nit: you should use `TryGetValue()`, taking advantage of the fact that the default value returned will be `0` if the key is not present, rather than first checking for the key and then retrieving the value (double lookup). For small inputs, it won't matter, but it's a better precedent to set, and will ensure efficient operation on large inputs.